# Correct way to return results from linq to sql between dates

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a little problem with a query.

I have two datetime textboxes and a button to search.

When I search let's say from 12/08/2021 to 12/08/2021 it returns only one result which has date 2021-08-12 00:00:00.000 because the time on the other invoices is 2021-08-12 17:38:55.740

My code is:

```
SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(fromDateEdit.DateTime, toDateEdit.DateTime);

public List<Invoices> SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    List<Invoices> invoices = db.Invoices
                                .Where(p => (p.Date >= fromDate && p.Date <= toDate));

    return invoices;
}
```

The two variables have values

> fromDate =12/8/2021 12:00:00
>
> toDate = 12/8/2021 12:43:21

I know that it doesnt return the other invoices because of the time, I just want to know if there is an elegant way to return all invoices from date 0:00:00 to 23:59:59

[image]

*in image the Imerominia = Date

Comment: When you say "I just want to know if there is an elegant way to return all invoices from date 0:00:00 to 12:00:00" do you mean a span of 12 hours? or is it incorrectly written and it should be read 00:00:00 AM to 12:00:00 PM?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot Yes you are right. I want to get all results from lets say 12.8.2021 00:00:00,000 to 12.8.2021 23:59:59,999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
I found how to do it.
I simply used
the addDays and addMilliseonds to get the right date.
Here is the code for anyone who will need it.

```
    public List<Invoices> SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        List<Invoices> invoices = db.Invoices
                               .Where(p => (p.Date >= fromDate.Date 
                               && p.Date <= toDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)));
    
        return invoices;
    }
```

Comment: You wouldnt have to do the addmilliseconds thing if you just used a LESS THAN operator `<` (and indeed you should just use "less than next day" rather that "less than or equal to 1 millisecond less than next day")

Comment: if the query were "numbers between 1 and 2, but not 2" then you wouldn't do `>=1 and <= 1.99` because then you'd have "what about 1.999?", to which you might reply ok, so `<=1.999` then.. "what about 1.9999?".. it's just `< 2` then you don't have to worry about "how many decimal places can we 1.999999999 to.."

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

New informations lead to corrections

The `Date` member of the `DateTime` class returns a new `DateTime` instance, with the `TimeOfDay` property set at 00:00:00. It does not return a new type that would not contain a time of day information.

For instance:

```cs
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay      // is 11:26:34.1234567
DateTime.Now.Date.TimeOfDay // is 00:00:00
```

So you can achieve what you need either by following @AsifRahman answer, or by using the principle of my original answer.

@AsifRahman solution is based on setting the `TimeOfDay` property to 00:00:00 in all the `DateTime` instances you will be using for comparison. This is done easily by using the `Date` property on all `DateTime` instances involved.

Notice that this solution uses an included upper bound
 `p.Date.Date <= toDate.Date`, which might not be ideal from a clarity perspective: the consequent intervals seems to be overlapping, but they are not.

The other solution is to use an exclusive upper bound and add one day to the `toDate.Date` value.

```cs
SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(fromDateEdit.DateTime, toDateEdit.DateTime);

public List<Invoices> SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    List<Invoices> invoices = db.Invoices.Where(p => (p.Date >= fromDate.Date && p.Date < toDate.Date.AddDay(1)));

    return invoices;
}
```

This has the benefit of being more clear (no overlapping of consequent intervals).

Comment: I gave wrong time to toDate. I meant to write 23:59:59. So I want from the start of the day to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

In a quick way, you can do something like this. so it'll only check and compare with dates but no time.

```
public List<Invoices> SearchInvoicesNotSendToMydata(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
     {
       List<Invoices> invoices = db.Invoices.Where(p => (p.Date.Date >= fromDate.Date && p.Date.Date <= toDate.Date));

       return invoices;
     }
```

Comment: I already tried that but this still returns wrong results

Comment: Did you really do `p.Date.Date` as in the answer? if you just do `p.Date`it won't work.